# Selection sort growing ordered ranges from both ends

Tags: java, sorting, duplicates, selection-sort

I have written a modified version of selection sort where I consider both a minimum and maximum of an array and place them at the two ends

The algorithm works like this

```
1. Find the minimum and the maximum value in the list.
2. Swap the minimum value with the value in the first position.
3. Swap the maximum value with the value in the last position.
4. Repeat the steps above for the remainder of the list 
(starting at the second position and ending at the second to 
 last position and narrowing the range of positions examined 
 from both ends of the array each time).
```

Unfortunately the above is showing unexpected results for arrays having duplicates values.

For example,

```
[9, 37, 12, 1, 13, 31, 5, 37, 36, 29, 19, 22, 20, 15, -1, 23]
```

was sorted to

```
[-1, 1, 5, 9, 12, 13, 15, 19, 20, 22, 23, 29, 31, 37, 36, 37]
```

In fact, the main issue here is that the algorithm in general is not doing proper sorting for the elements in the latter part of the array, besides simply with respect to duplicates.

Here is my pseudocode

```
    int i=0;
    while(i<=(arr.length-i-1)) {
      int minIndex = i;
      int maxIndex=arr.length-i-1; 
      for (int j = i+1; j <=arr.length-i-1; j++) {

       if (arr[j] <=arr[minIndex]) {
         minIndex = j;      
         } 
       if(arr[j]>=arr[maxIndex]){
          maxIndex = j; 
         }
      }
      swap(arr, i, minIndex);
      swap(arr, (arr.length-i-1), maxIndex); 
    i++;
    }
```

**EDIT** This is the swap part of my code which is the only thing  that interacts with the algorithm. I don't think it will make any difference but I'll include it anyway

```
 private static void swap(int[] arr, int oldIndex, int newIndex){

    int temp=arr[oldIndex];
    arr[oldIndex]=arr[newIndex];
    arr[newIndex]=temp;
 }
```

Comment: Could you please post your complete code? I do not think there is error in what you show above.

Comment: Did you verify your swapping function ? can you post it ?

Comment: I do... but I can't visualise it. @LadiesMan217 - can you add another -1 to your array, and see if it does the same thing for the minimum?

Comment: @mjbnz Which step of the above code should i add it too?

Comment: @ladiesMan217 - no, to your input array, so that you have two of the minumum value.

Comment: I did but that didnt work either. There is another huge problem about the way its treating the latter part of the array. Its not just duplicates but sometimes elements such as `16` will lie somewhere like  `31, 32, 16, 42]`

Comment: See [SelectionSort variation not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26861058/3789665).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens when `i` happens to be the `maxIndex`. To fix that you need to add:

```
swap(arr, i, minIndex);
if(i == maxIndex) {
     maxIndex = minIndex;
}
swap(arr, (arr.length-i-1), maxIndex);
```

[**See it @work**](http://ideone.com/XZFAc)

Comment: there was an issue here too. I tried this with your method `[25, 38, 19, 38, 36, 3, -2, 27, 7, 29, 41, 3, -2, 14, -2, 23]` and the output was `[-2, -2, -2, 3, 3, 7, 14, 23, 19, 25, 27, 29, 36, 38, 38, 41]`. The issue is at `23, 19, 25`

Comment: Oh my mistake. I was starting my inner loop at `i+1` instead of `i`. Wait, could you try it for `odd number` inputs , 15 may be? I think I am getting even more of a screwed up result with an odd number input

Comment: So for size 15, input being `[41, 34, 29, 0, 27, 21, 35, 29, 9, 30, 37, 38, 34, 4, 38]` output was `[0, 9, 4, 21, 27, 29, 29, 30, 34, 34, 35, 37, 38, 38, 41]` with your method. Now issue lies in the first half, here at `0, 9, 4`

Comment: @ladiesMan217: I'm sure you are good with ladies, request you to get good with copying as well: http://ideone.com/oxwtI :P

Comment: @codaddict's solution definitely works.  It addresses the problem - if the first swap moves the maximum value, change 'maxIndex' to follow it.  Simple and effective and directly resolves the conflict, which my "parallel swap" still has trouble with.

Comment: @codaddict haha my mistake. I was using `i<arr.length` instead of your `i<=arr.length`. Now it works fine. Sorry I was too tired to notice such minor changes. Now its the only correct answer

Answer (score 2):

OK, the problem is the case where the maximum value starts in the minimum position of the iteration. Consider the second time through the loop on your problem array:

```
-1,37,12,1,13,31,5,23,36,29,19,22,20,15,9,37
```

i is 1, len-i-1 is 14. After the loop, maxindex is 1, and minIndex is 3.

So you swap 1 (i) and 3 (minIndex):

```
-1,1,12,37,13,31,5,23,36,29,19,22,20,15,9,37
```

And then 14 (len-i-1) and 1 (maxIndex):

```
-1,9,12,37,13,31,5,23,36,29,19,22,20,15,1,37
```

Oops.  Basically, you need to do both swaps in parallel.

**EDIT** Parallelism won't really help in the case of two overlapping swaps, since each of the swaps wants to put a different value in one of the array slots; you have to resolve the conflict.  I think @codaddict's solution works well.

Comment: Bingo - that's what my subconcious was seeing, but I just couldn't visualise it.

Comment: How can I do a parallel swap? Seems difficult to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error in the termination condition of the inner for loop..

```
  for (int j = i+1; j <=arr.length-i-1; j++) {
```

that should be a `<`, not a `<=`, for the same reason you start with `i+1` instead of `i`.

As a stylistic recommendation, I would also store the value `arr.length - i - 1` in a variable, since it shows up four times in the code.

**EDIT**: verified this error is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Nope. this is wrong. if i=0 then the above expression works simply fine. I tried your modification but it didn't have any effect

Comment: No this is not a problem - he will simply try the last index once more -this should not affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing too many swaps - i.e. you're doing the swaps regardless of whether you've actually found a new min or max value. Also, you don't need to do both tests (of min and max, as you cannot be both, except in the trivial case of equality, in which case it doesn't matter which order they're in...).

I submit that the following is a better representation of your algorithm:

```
int arrayLength = arr.length;
for (int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){
  for (int j=i+1; j<arrayLength; j++){
    int v = arr[j];
    if (v < arr[i]){
      swap(arr, i, j);
    } else if (v > arr[(arrayLength -1)]){
      swap(arr, (arrayLength -i-1), j);
    }
  }
}
```

However, you don't actually need to do the tests on the max values to swap them to the end, as these will all be caught by the search for min values as you do you top-level iteration through your array - i.e.

```
int arrayLength = arr.length;
for (int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){
  for (int j=i+1; j<arrayLength; j++){
    int v = arr[j];
    if (v < arr[i]){
      swap(arr, i, j);
    } 
  }
}
```

would be more efficient.

EDIT: Having reviewed the other answers, this sort of picks up on Mark Reed's answer about doing the swaps in parallel - except that, I'd suggest you do the swaps as you've found the need to.

Answer (score -2):

Well as in the comments, your first swap will do well, but your second swap makes an issue.

In the case when your maxindex variable was located at i, you placed your minimum term correctly, but lost your max term. This can be tackled by adding an extra provision that checks `if(i==maxterm)`, and handle this special case by making first swap normally and second swap of maxterm and minterm locations secondly. It is useless for you to traverse through your array from 0 to `array.length-1`

I recommend, traverse from 0 to (array.length-1)/2, as you are sorting on both side. The end part is already sorted as is the starting part, why make extra iterations ? I have written an exactly same program with corrections I suggested which also checks if the numbers are already sorted and terminates loop immediately.

Comment: Please avoid using "..." as replacement for all punctuation marks. Full stops, comma, etc. are cool as well ! And improves readability.